# Django Comments: How to update page based on model instance returned by successful post?

Tags: javascript, django, signals, comments

When a user posts a new comment, I want to display that comment immediately on the page with information derived from the new comment model instance. (For example, including a live 'favorite' button that requires the instance id, and a delete button which works.)

I know that when [Django Comments](https://django-contrib-comments.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) successfully posts content to the `{% comment_form_target %}` url it performs the `comment_was_posted` signal.

How do I capture this signal, or otherwise derive the newly created content model instance so that the I can insert html featuring information from this model instance into the page?

If I was doing this with ajax, I would pass the model instance or its pk back as part of the success message. But I don't know how to do this with the django comments library.

Comment: Do you mean update the HTML for everyone's view of the page?  Live?

Comment: Only the poster. Visitor is viewing a user's profile. They add a comment and hit submit. The comment is displayed.